# Does improved grapple count in determinig the CMB when casting while grappled

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I've always stayed away from grapple & overrun rules, but, this time, i can't ignore it.

The rules says that

> A grappled character who attempts to cast a spell or use a spell-like
> ability must make a concentration check (DC 10 + grappler’s CMB +
> spell level, see Concentration)

so does the feat, special abilities, objects granting bonus on the grapple check count against the DC of concentration?

Does the bonus like flanking count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, these bonuses don't apply.

The [Improved Grapple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-grapple-combat/) feat states:

> In addition, you receive a +2 bonus on checks made to grapple a foe.  You also receive a +2 bonus to your Combat Maneuver Defense whenever an opponent tries to grapple you.

The feat doesn't increase your CMB, it just gives you a bonus on "checks made to grapple"
and to your CMD. So the concentration DC to cast a spell doesn't increase.  Similarly, since flanking doesn't improve your CMB it also doesn't affect the concentration DC.

Comment: It's possible the bonus from flanking applies. On **Performing a [Combat Maneuver**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Combat-Maneuver-Bonus) says, "When you attempt to perform a combat maneuver, make an attack roll and add your CMB in place of your normal attack bonus. **Add any bonuses you currently have on attack rolls due to spells, feats, and other effects.** These bonuses must be applicable to the weapon or attack used to perform the maneuver" (emphases mine).

Comment: Flanking is still a bonus, not an increase to your CMB.